# Specifying connection clears selected database?

Tags: php, mysql, resources

O,

it is really the bottom line where the question kicks in.. But you may want the other info afterwards like how I connected and so on to avoid misunderstandings. :)

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '******');

if(!$con) {
    die('Could not establish connection: ' . mysql_error);
}


mysql_select_db('hunkusersystem');

function user_login($username, $password) {

    //Avoid SQL-injections.
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    //Match user and password
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersystem WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1", **$con**);
```

My question is - in the very last block of code, I can not use the resource id.. Why is that? Is it because the mysql_select_db would be "cleared"? So you stand with correct connection but no database? If I would use several connections, should I define the connection in the mysql_select_db(); ?

Thank you very much for your help :)
Greets from Swe.

Comment: New applications **SHOULD NOT USE** `mysql_query` for making queries. Although you've been careful to escape your data here, if you ever forget to do this you could face serious consequences. Using [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is essential.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Thanks guys! So I guess PDO it is if you trust the article :) and nice handbook tadman. Many thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 4):

It's a scope issue; the function `user_login` can't see `$con`, because it's not been passed in as a parameter or declared as a global variable.

(Please don't declare it as a global variable; it's very bad practice)

Try:

```
function user_login($username, $password, $con) {
```

Comment: Oh, so that is why! What do you mean with bad practice? :) that I should challenge myself to work around it? Or is it a bad habit and something you should avoid to use a connection as a global variable, or globals in general? Thank you for your addition!

Comment: @henrikjohan - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357187/when-are-global-variables-acceptable . If you've got connections which are effectively read-only once they're made, then you can justify having a global, but I prefer trying to avoid them if it all possible.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$con` is defined in the global scope and not in the local scope of the function.

If you want to use it there, you can use:

```
function user_login($username, $password) {
    global $con;
```

However, you'd better pass the variable to the function as a parameter.

The best solution would be to move to PDO / mysqli with prepared statements and use dependency injection but that's outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: Well, I am one of those who likes when things come outside the scope. I don't really now what to ask for, so this comes in handy! :) If you have any other tips for a beginner (tips that the professionals endores) please do share.

Comment: @henrikjohan I would recommend using PDO and OOP, that way you can keep all your components nicely organized and easily reuse them in other projects when necessary.